# How can I get free Baggage Allowance with GetReservationRQ or TravelItineraryReadRQ

Tags: sabre

I am retrieving reservations with GetReservationRQ and TravelItineraryReadRQ but there is no information about baggage allowance in the response.
How can I get the information about baggage allowance (number of items and weight) after ticketing?

Here is what I received from GetReservationRS:

```
<SegmentInfo number="1" segmentStatus="OK">
    ...
    <FareBasis>AAPVNF96</FareBasis>
    <NotValidBefore>2021-02-08</NotValidBefore>
    <NotValidAfter>2021-02-08</NotValidAfter>
    <Baggage allowance="01" type="P"/>
</SegmentInfo>
```

Here is what I received from TravelItineraryReadRQ:

```
<tir310:FlightSegment ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="02-08T07:00" FlightNumber="207" ResBookDesigCode="A" SegmentNumber="1" Status="OK">
    <tir310:BaggageAllowance Number="01P"/>
    <tir310:FareBasis Code="AAPVNF96"/>
    <tir310:MarketingAirline Code="VN" FlightNumber="207"/>
    <tir310:OriginLocation LocationCode="HAN"/>
    <tir310:ValidityDates>
        <tir310:NotValidAfter>2021-02-08</tir310:NotValidAfter>
        <tir310:NotValidBefore>2021-02-08</tir310:NotValidBefore>
    </tir310:ValidityDates>
</tir310:FlightSegment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to develop airline check-in software that integrated with sabre and getting the baggage allowance was always much harder than you think it should be.  The sabre web services didn't return a complete figure for the passengers baggage entitlement.  It did return baggage allowances associated with the faretype, but didn't take other factors into consideration like:-

- does the passenger have any baggage ancillaries that would increase their bag count or weight allowance?  You can get passenger ancillaries in the response from sabre web services, so can implement logic to tally them up if you need to.
- does the passenger have a frequent flyer program and tier that would give them additional baggage allowances?  This also needs to take into account partner airline frequent flyer programs.  There is a customer entitlement table in sabre where baggage allowances for frequent flyer tiers can be configured for routes.
- Is the passenger on an international flight with a connection operated or marketed by another airline?  If so, the 'most significant carrier' on that journey needs to be identified and that carriers baggage allowance rules would apply.  This one is harder because it requires knowledge of other airline baggage rules.

Getting a single value for baggage allowance wasn't implemented by the sabre web services at the time I was looking into it.  Sabre did say however that they were working on it.  I'm not sure where they are at with that.

ATPCO do offer a subscription to an API that claims to return baggage allowances, taking into account all of the above.  See https://developer.atpco.net/.